# ItemizedOverlay, OverlayItem, Overlay.. display moving markers on map?

Tags: android, maps

I need to display and move markers (representing friend's locations) around in a mapview in Android 2.2.

At the moment I have extended `ItemizedOverlay` and `OverlayItem`, but I am not sure this is the best way to do it.

First of all should I have 1 `ItemizedOverlay` with many `OverlayItem` (one per marker) or each marker should have its own `ItemizedOverlay`? In case of the latter, should I extend Overlay instead?

Secondly, what is the best practice to move markers around? Destroy change point redraw? :|

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end I am just using the `ItemizedOverlay`+`OverlayItem` structure.

I am creating the overlay item on-the-fly in the `createItem(int index)` method, I suppose this is not the best solution (performance-wise) but anyways..